# i18next Interpolation with strong tag

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Let's say I have a key like so:

```
{ key1: "my name is {{name, bold}}" }
```

I was hoping to have a function like so:

```
i18next.init({
    interpolation: {
        format: function(value, format, lng) {
            if (format === 'bold') return <strong>{value}</string>;
            return value;
        }
    }
});
```

But I get the following error:

> 'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

Is there any way I can make this happen? I really want to use interpolation for some simple custom styling in my i18n placeholders.

Comment: You forgot about `import React from 'react'`;

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko Ah thank you i forgot. after that for some reason I get `[object Object]` as my value that is returned. I even tried `return React.createElement('strong', null, value);`